# SecurityException when calling System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()

Tags: c#, silverlight, io, elevated-privileges

I'm working on a silverlight elevated trust application. I made a call to

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

I am getting a Security Exception, message "File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied."

```
Application.Current.HasElevatedPermissions
```

Returns true

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I think you can't do this stuff from the Silverlight sandbox.  Try [isolated storage instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bdts8hk0%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Old answer:
From [Path.GetTempPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx):

This method checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:

1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
4. The Windows directory.

Perhaps you can use [System.Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: My goal is to save an excel sheet tempoarily using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.saveas(v=vs.80).aspx, I don't think I can get this method to use isolated storage.

Comment: Maybe `Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Personal)` would work

Comment: Environment.GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.Personal) works. Thanks!